# Vue.D3.tree - Vue component to display tree is not working properly

Tags: vue.js, d3.js

I used Vue.D3.tree dependency with the sample code provided at

https://vuejsexamples.com/vue-component-to-display-tree-based-on-d3-js-layout/

in code sandbox https://codesandbox.io/s/hopeful-fire-vpq5z?file=/src/App.vue:0-853.

I need to build complex tree based on that sample code. The tree is getting built but is very small(not visible initially) and continuously moving towards down and growing in size. Not sure what im missing. How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: Looks like you've done everything by the book. I'd [raise an issue](https://github.com/David-Desmaisons/Vue.D3.tree/issues) but keep in mind, this could also be a CodeSandbox issue. Have you tried running it locally?

Comment: Actually, looks like this issue ~ https://github.com/David-Desmaisons/Vue.D3.tree/issues/28

Comment: Thanks @Phil, I have added style="max-width: 500px;max-height: 500px" to the tree component to fix the issue.